# Memoir gets page number of table of contents wrong

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir

The following MWE produces a one-page document with the table of contents still on the first page.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum

\tableofcontents
\end{document}
```

If I make `\tableofcontents` clear the page first explicitly by adding

```
\renewcommand{\tocheadstart}{\clearpage}
```

to the preamble, I get the ToC on page 2, but the entry for Contents lists it as on page 1.

Why?

(memoir 2021/06/16 v3.7p, pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.23)

Comment: Never has, some people want a page break others don't, so memoir does not force it. I typically just add a `\clearforchapter` before it. And perhaps after it depending on the document

Comment: Fair enough, I should have checked what `\chapterheadstart` does. I'm mainly concerned about the incorrect page number. I'll edit the question.

Comment: Did you compile enough times?

Comment: Yes, ..........

Comment: That is because `\tocheadstart` is executed after `\tableofcontents` writes it self to the toc. This is done such that any hyperref to to (say from a book mark) jumps above the header, not below it. As mentioned, it is s lot easier to just use `\clearforchapter`, or use the `\tableofcontents*` which does not add it self to the toc.

Comment: Looking at the code there isn't much you can do in terms of hooks or macros to get the `\chaperpage` into the macro sort of patching.

Comment: That's what I was wondering. I wanted to provide a class based on memoir that makes the ToC on a new page automatically, like the standard classes do.

Comment: Book and report explicitly uses chapter* in the toc definition. Memoir does don't. Design choice I guess. You can just save the definition (`\let` or the xparse copy command that is now in the kernel) and then redefine to include a clearforchapter (I would not use clearpage directly)

Answer (score 1):

Use `\addtodef` instead to make `\tableofcontents` call `\clearpage` or `\clearforchapter` etc. before it does anything else.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\addtodef{\tableofcontents}{\clearforchapter}{}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
Lorem ipsum

\tableofcontents
\end{document}
```